# How to avoid N+1 when reindexing models with Searchkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, opensearch, searchkick

I am using searchkick to wrap OpenSearch.
My `Program` model has this `search_data`:

```rb
{
  name: name,
  description: description,
  provider_name: provider.name,
  category: category&.name,
  age_min: age_min || 0,
  age_max: age_max || 999,
  start_dates: current_published_schedules.pluck(:start_date),
  zipcode: address&.zipcode,
  program_type: program_type
}
```

When I run the reindex task:

```
Program.reindex(refresh: true)
```

I see in the logs that many SQL queries for Provider and Schedule have been made, one for each Program.
Is there a way to tell Searchkick to "`includes`" or "`preload`" somehow to optimize the reindexing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully in searchkick eager load method is available, we can use includes with help of the *search_import* method.

You can refer more about on searchkick documentation [here](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#performant-conversions).

From above sample data, i have seen your program table have has one association with provider, category, etc. with help of that i try to give sample examples below, hope it might helps to you.

### Program Model

From inside of model you need to write as

```
scope :search_import, -> { includes(:provider, :category, :current_published_schedules) }
```

Now When you hit the reindex, it first eager loads the all association data what you have mentioned in search import. Now it continuously fires the single query for each program data to update in elastic.

Hope this helps to fix your issue :)

Comment: I don't know who you are but I love you. Thank you. This was exactly what I needed

Comment: Hello Leticia I'm happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use their [documentation](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#performant-conversions) mentions you can cache those values in the DB level